# Why is $\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1$ the equation of an elliptical cylinder?

Tags: conic-sections, quadrics

I'm attempting to graph the function: $$\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1$$

I can tell that at constant $z$ the graph is elliptical, but I found, at constant $x$ and $y$, let's say $x=0$, $y=0$:

Let $y=0$
$$\frac{x^2}{4} -1 = z$$

This is parabolic.

For $x=0$:

$$\frac{y^2}{9}-1=z$$

This is also parabolic. However, according to the answer for this exercise this object is an elliptical cylinder, yet I can't understand how would that be possible given the fact that it's quadratic in the $xz$ and $yz$ planes. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: If you replace $y$ with $0$ in the first equation, how does your right-hand side change from $1$ to $z$?

Comment: It's an elliptic paraboloid. (I assume that you meant in your first equation $\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} =z$.) Did you try graphing it?

Comment: I have taken the iberty to modify your title and your tags in order that more "specialized" people are attracted by your question, in the present and in the future.

Answer (score 4):

If you intersect with plane $y=0$ you get $\frac{x^2}{4}=1$ which is a pair of straight lines in the plane $y=0$ equations $x=2;\;x=-2$. And for $x=0$ a similar thing happens $\frac{y^2}{9}=1$ pair of lines in the plane $x=0$, namely $y=3;\;y=-3$

The elliptic thing is that in any plane $z=k$ the intersection is $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$, an ellipse as you can see in the picture below

[image]

Comment: [+1] I appreciate the use of graphics for convincing students that one cannot have geometrical insight without drawing figures at least from time to time,

Comment: I see, you get two straight lines (which would allow for it to be a cylinder) with the equation $\frac{x^2}{4} = 1$, which is different from mine with $\frac{x^2}{4} -1 = z$, is something I did because I assumed it's in the $xz$ plane so must be a function of $z$. Why is doing what I did incorrect?